# My invoice link returns nill

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

When the user  clicks on 'send invoice', the invoice show link is sent to the client's email. However, I get this error each time I click on send

```
"undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass"
```

**Email message view**

```
<h3>Hi <%= @client.try(:first_name) %></h3>

<p>Click the link below to view invoice</p>

<%= link_to 'INVOICE', edit_invoice_url(@invoice.id) %>
```

**User mailer controller**

```
def show
  @user=current_user
  @client=Client.find_by(params[:client_id])
  @invoice = @client.invoices.find_by(id: params[:id])
end

def update
  @user=User.find_by(params[:user_id])
  @client = Client.find_by(params[:client_id])
  @invoice = Invoice.find_by(params[:qty])

  if @invoice
    UserMailer.invoice_mail(@client).deliver
    flash[:change_pass] = "Invoice sent successfully!"
    redirect_to client_path(@user.company_name)
  end
end
```

**Send invoice link**

```
<%= link_to 'send', invoice_path(@invoice), method: :patch %>
```

Comment: The `{}` button usually formats code correctly in the editor. I've cleaned it up a little to be easier to read.

Comment: It looks like the invoice isn't being found. You may need to render out a "not found" page in the case where `@invoice` is not defined.

Comment: yea i know,thats the problem,how do i make @invoice visible then?

Comment: It seems the result of the `find_by` call is failing, so maybe the record is missing or the `params[:id]` value is incorrect. Hard to say from here. If it's really important that the record be loaded, `find_by!` will freak out if it's not found. Then you can `rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` to display a message if necessary, or have a more global `rescue_from` handler.

Comment: Wait, are you sure an invoice actually exist for that client when the email is sent? Seems to me like @invoice is returning nothing ... because @client.invoices.find_by(id: params[:id]) returns nothing.

Comment: @client actually returns its expected value, note: the invoice is created when user clicks on 'preview' but it is then sent when user clicks on send button which is on the preview page.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because `find_by` finder require an attribute for right SQL query.

And if you want to find instance by id - you have to use `find` method.

For example:

```
> Box.find_by(3)
=> Box Load (3.1ms)  SELECT  "boxes".* FROM "boxes" WHERE (3) LIMIT 1
   PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type integer
```

and `Box.find_by(id: 3)` will return an object (if exist) like `Box.find(3)`

Comment: No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"invoices", :format=>nil, :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]                                                                                                                       
 
thats what i get whenever i try your method @esergion

Comment: thats what i get whenever i try your method @esergion

Comment: sorry, need to sleep sometimes..

can you show output of `rake routes |grep invoice`?